# Compiler doesnt recognise property in generic if declaration is an interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Have a look at the following that demonstrates my issue with Visual Studio 2017 compiler

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Key { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintFoo(new Foo() { Key = "Hello World" });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintFoo<T>(T foo) where T : IFoo
    {
        //set breakpoint here and try to look at foo.Key
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Key);
    }
}
```

When I make a breakpoint inside the `PrintFoo` method and want to look at the `Key` property of `foo` Visual Studio wont provide a tooltip for me.
By adding the `foo.Key` to the watch window I receive the following error:

> error CS1061: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no
>   extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I change the generic declaration to `Foo` instead of `IFoo` the compiler can acces the 'Key' property, so this:

```
private static void PrintFoo<T>(T foo) where T : Foo
{
    //set breakpoint here and try to look at foo.Key
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Key);
}
```

Is there a way to make it work?

**Edit:**

Both, looking at the local window and mouse over `foo` to get the tooltip and than expanding the properties works.

Adding `foo.Key` to the watch window or writing `?foo.Key` into immediate window brings the mentioned error, and you wont get a tooltip when you mouse over `Key` of `foo.Key`

Tested with Visual Studio 2015, 2017.

[image: Error in watch VS window]

Comment: you may tr to *cast* to `Foo` inside watch window. Should help.

Comment: @Tigran casting gives `error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'T' to 'Foo'` - could cast to object and after that too `Foo` but yeah... kinda annoying

Comment: Maybe don't rely on the implicit `T` defining, try using: `PrintFoo<Foo>(new Foo() { Key = "Hello World" });`

Comment: @maccettura - that may help in this situation but I am kind-of looking for a more general solution the provided code is a simple demonstration of the problem - imagine an interface with thousands of implementations (yes, way to many) but I desire a solution for all those cases for it to work

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and when breaking on `Console.WriteLine(foo.Key);` I expanded `foo` in Locals and it showed `Key` as "Hello World". No error for me.

Comment: LINQPad also correctly shows the value of foo.Key within the PrintFoo function. What version of Visual Studio are you working with?

Comment: @BlakeThingstad yes, local works just as when I mouse over foo and expand the properties there but it fails when I access it "directly" - did you try to mouse over `foo.Key` (directly Key) or write `foo.Key` in watch window?

Comment: @JonathonChase tested with 2017 and 2015

Comment: Now I am receiving the error. I had to put a watch on foo.Key. Also, doing `PrintFoo<Foo>(...);` did not fix it for me.

Comment: just tested it myself, and yes @maccettura solution doesnt work for me aswell

Comment: @BlakeThingstad can you verify that changing `IFoo` to `Foo` works? in the declaration `where T : IFoo` ?

Comment: yes, changing from `IFoo` to `Foo` makes the error go away and show "Hello World" when watching foo.Key

Comment: JetBrains Rider shows the value correctly. Quickwatch on foo.Key in VS 2017 gives CS1061. Issue looks VS specific.

Comment: I added a screenshot so it is clear exactly where the error occurs. Feel free to roll back my edit if you do not think it adds anything.

Comment: That said it looks like a bug in VS. The best course of action would be to [report it to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017).

Comment: @Igor - thx for the screenshot

Comment: I'm going to ask a stupid question: what's the advantage of doing `private static void PrintFoo<T>(T foo) where T : IFoo`  compared to `private static void PrintFoo(IFoo foo)`?

Comment: @Richardissimo there is none in this case, but this code is to only demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug got fixed in Visual Studio 2019:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/216341/compiler-doesnt-recognise-property-in-generic-if-d.html

Comment by Ivan Basov [MSFT]:

> It seems that the issue is not reproducible in the current Visual
>   Studio. I tried it with VS 2019 Preview 2. The scenario works fine.
>   Thank you for your feedback!

Also tried to reproduce it on my Preview Version 1.1 and it is fixed there aswell.

Gave the latest Version of Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.5) a try aswell and can report it got fixed there aswell.

Answer (score 5):

There are two workarounds for this issue. Use Tools > Options > Debugging > General. You can tick "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" or "Use the legacy C# and VB.NET expression evaluators".

"Use Managed Compatibility Mode" is unnecessarily cryptic, what it actually does is replace the new debugging engine with the one that was last used in VS2010.  The good one.  It in effect also gives you the legacy expression evaluator.  I recommend you use this one since it also avoids a bunch of other bugs in the new debugging engine.  Which got especially buggy in VS2015.

Very few reasons I ever discovered to turn it back off.  You miss out on recently added debugger features, I only know of method return value inspection, edit+continue for 64-bit code and the new portable PDB format that is used in .NETCore on non-Windows systems.  It *must* be used to debug C++/CLI code.  I don't know what is better about the new expression evaluator, never noticed anything.  Pretty easy to live without them, at least for me.

I'm not privy enough to the internals of the debugger team to really tell what is going on.  But it doesn't look that good, VS2017 added some new nasty failure modes with the new debugging engine collapsing into a pile of rubble at the worst possible time.  Take these options at their face value, they surely exist because they know the latest versions are not up to snuff.

---

Update: as pointed out by Rand, this particular defect does appear to have been addressed.  I'm seeing correct behavior in version 15.9.3.

Comment: Comment to update you, in case you missed it. Thought you may be interessted in knowing it got fixed, maybe its time for you to give the new debugger another chance. :)