# Errors in my debugger environment, does an upgrade exist?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

[As mentioned yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71248808/difference-in-variable-scope-between-c-c-and-c-sharp-or-a-quirk-in-the-debugge), I'm having some issues with my debugger (sometimes it shows wrong values).
This morning I almost exploded on this particular case:

[image]

I was interested in information about the DB, used by my application, so I put a breakpoint on a line, where the corresponding object is used. As the debugger said that particular object is `null`, I was extremely surprised being capable to the following line, as you can see in the screenshot.

For me, this is the clearest proof that my debugger is so bogus and I would like to update it, but I don't know how. My current visual studio about mentions the following:

[image]

In text format:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.9.44
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.44+28307.1800
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Enterprise

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2017   00370-00007-85954-AA413
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2017
```

Is there a known issue for this particular visual studio version, .Net framework version, Telerik version, ...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49318426/17034

Comment: You should consider updating to VS2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 15.9.44 is, as of today, the latest available build for VS2017. You should consider upgrading to VS2022. To upgrade, just download the latest visual studio installer from microsoft (https://microsoft.com/vstudio). It lets you select the version to install. You can install VS2017, VS2019 and VS2022 in parallel (given enough free disk space).